# java splitting textboxes using bufferreader

Tags: java, android, string, split, bufferedreader

Hi I am figuring out how to split the strings so heres my code:
because i using bufferedreader and i have two textboxes so it reads both the text boxes (the 1st textbox i type john), the second textbox i type peter) the output is johnpeter so i trying to split the textboxes instead of reading just 1 line straight.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            req.getInputStream()));
         String name;

    while ((name = reader.readLine().toString()) != null) 
    {

        Statement stmt;


  String[] players = name.split("");
        String playerO = players[1]; 
        String playerX = players[2];
```

Current output is:

```
Player 1 :j
Player 2 :o
```

I would like my output to be:

```
Player 1 :john
Player 2 :peter
```

Comment: Well, split on what??

Comment: @JigarJoshi Probably the lack of quotes on `johnpeter`

Comment: You're better off doing a substring, because the character you split on gets lost in the process. But that means you would need to know the length of what the 2 parts will be. Why not add a , between the parts then do split(",")

Comment: because i using bufferreader it read the line straight ,so i want to split them

Comment: This once more won't compile, the while loop lacks an end

Answer (score 3):

As is, you won't be able to split the string where you want to, as there's no clear delimiting character. If you stored it as "john peter" or "john,peter" or something like that, it would be easier to split.

Then you would just need to change

`String[] players = name.split("");`

to 
`String[] players = name.split(" ");`

or `String[] players = name.split(",");`

Also, as others have mentioned, remember that the first item in `players` is `players[0]`, not `players[1]`

Answer (score 1):

As others have alluded to, your original string "johnpeter" needs to instead be something like

```
"john,peter,joey,tom,dick,harry";
```

then you can

```
String name = "john,peter,joey,tom,dick,harry"; 
String[] players = name.split(",");
String playerO = players[0]; 
String playerX = players[1];


System.out.println("Player 1 :" + players[O]);//or, playerO
System.out.println("Player 2 :" + players[1]);//or, playerX
```

Note the zero-base of the array, as well. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you trying to do since split("on what").

Try some thing like this if space between names,

```
    String name = "john peter";
    String[] players = name.split(" ");
    String playerO = players[0];
    String playerX = players[1];


    System.out.println("Player 1 :" +playerO);
    System.out.println("Player 2 :" +playerX);
```

If you want to split("??") there should be (split on what) identifier